# PowerShell | OLEDB | Excel | Unable to read data from XLSX created from third-party app

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb

**Update (2012.12.13) - added sample code, input formatting, output sample

I've been fighting with this for a few days, now, and I've run out of ideas.  I've tested a script (and can upload later once I have it in front of me) successfully against multiple XLSX files.  I've got the connection string functional, parsing the data that I need, etc...

The issue is that when I attempt to process my input files (generated from a third-party reporting application) the data is not read from the worksheet.

If I open and save the input file within Excel (no format changes, no data entry/removal, no modifications at all), the input file will then process and parse all data.

I've tried using multiple 'Extended Properties' settings in the connection string, to no avail, including HDR=Yes/No and IMEX=1.

Anyone ever see anything like this before?

---

```
#inputFile_original.xlsx will not parse the data from the worksheet
#inputFile_original_reSaved.xlsx parses the data without any issues

$fileName  = "inputFile_original.xlsx"
#$fileName = "inputFile_original_reSaved.xlsx"
$filePath  = ".\OLEDB\test\"

#Build the connection string
$ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
$ConnectionString += (Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath $fileName)
$ConnectionString += ";OLE DB Services=-4;Extended Properties="
$ConnectionString += '"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";'

$conn   = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($ConnectionString)
$conn.Open()

$tables = $conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::tables,$null)

$cmd    = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [$($tables.rows[0].TABLE_NAME)]",$conn)

$da     = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)
$ds     = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da.Fill($ds)

#Output the data to the console
$ds.tables
```

---

Also, the input file is not formatted in a really easily used layout.  Again, due to being generated from a third-party application.

There are blank lines and the header row doesn't start on row 1.

```
      A           B           C           D           E           F
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
01 | ReportTitle
02 |
03 | ColHeader1  ColHeader2  ColHeader3  ColHeader4  ColHeader5  ColHeader6
04 | Data        Data        Data        Data        Data        Data
05 | Data        Data        Data        Data        Data        Data
06 | Data        Data        Data        Data        Data        Data
07 | Data        Data        Data        Data        Data        Data
08 | Data        Data        Data        Data        Data        Data
09 |
10 | Total: 5
```

The output that I'm receiving is shown below.
(A) original file

```
Report Title :
F2           :
F3           :
F4           :
F5           :
F6           :

Report Title : ColHeader1
F2           : 
F3           : 
F4           : 
F5           : 
F6           :
```

(B) re-saved file

```
Report Title :
F2           :
F3           :
F4           :
F5           :
F6           :

Report Title : ColHeader1
F2           : ColHeader2
F3           : ColHeader3
F4           : ColHeader4
F5           : ColHeader5
F6           : ColHeader6

Report Title : Data
F2           : Data
F3           : Data
F4           : Data
F5           : Data
F6           : Data

Report Title : Data
F2           : Data
F3           : Data
F4           : Data
F5           : Data
F6           : Data

Report Title : Data
F2           : Data
F3           : Data
F4           : Data
F5           : Data
F6           : Data

Report Title : Data
F2           : Data
F3           : Data
F4           : Data
F5           : Data
F6           : Data

Report Title : Data
F2           : Data
F3           : Data
F4           : Data
F5           : Data
F6           : Data

Report Title :
F2           :
F3           :
F4           :
F5           :
F6           :

Report Title : Total: 5
F2           :
F3           :
F4           :
F5           :
F6           :
```

Comment: Could it be something related to Protected View where a downloaded or e-mailed file is more restricted?  When you re-save, it's local and less restricted.

Comment: It could be HTML, CSV or TEXT format, only has .xlsx extension. If its really XLSX you can unzip it with 7-Zip.

Comment: @DWright - From what I can tell it doesn't appear to be a protected document.  Thanks, though.  I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: @9dan - It is a true XLSX file. I unzipped the file via 7z yesterday to validate.

Comment: @vidrine - You might want to review settings in File | Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings (button).  Look at ActiveX, Macros (are there macros in the document?), Protected View, Message Bar, File Block Settings.

Comment: @DWright - Settings are all off or extremely minimal.

Comment: @vidrine - I sympathize with the prob, must be super-annoying.  I'm out of ideas what it could be, but how about you just script opening and saving the user-supplied  file and saving as part of your script.  That'll get you around the problem, even if no explanation of the problem is forthcoming.

Comment: @DWright - Always an option; I was just attempting to touch the files as few times as possible.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening the Excel files with OLEDB, you could just open them in Excel from Powershell... This is a quick sample that just prints the size of sheets. The only issue I learned with it was that you had to fully quit out of Excel every time and purge any remnant of it (the GC stuff at the end.)

```
foreach($File in $excelFiles)
{
   $excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
   $excel.visible = $false
   $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File)

   write-host "There are $($workbook.Sheets.count) sheets in $File"
   For($i = 1 ; $i -le $workbook.Sheets.count ; $i++)
   {
     $worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item($i)
     $rowMax = ($worksheet.usedRange.rows).count
     $columnMax = ($worksheet.usedRange.columns).count
     write-host "Sheet $($i) ($($worksheet.Name)) has dimensions $($rowMax) x $($columnMax)"

   $worksheet = $rowMax = $columnMax = $null
   } #end for
$workbook.close($false)
$workbook = $null
$excel.quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

} #end foreach
```

Comment: My current script is actually leveraging this method - COM Objects.  The issue that I'm encountering, however, is that when the script runs via MS Scheduled Tasks when no user is logged in the script fails.  It's unable to connection/parse data via COM Objects.  That's what led me to researching OLEDB connections and trying to test them out.   _I really wish I could just get my data source in a non-MS format (CSV, XML, something), but that isn't possible apparently._

Comment: Your second problem sounds like one I know as well. You need to make sure it runs as a user that has a profile initialized. Poke around on ServerFault for answers about that.

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  I'll start looking around.  I actually pulled SQL queries today, so I may be avoiding these input files and getting data directly now.  Still interested to see this working, though.

Comment: Late to the party... $ComExcelWorkSheet.SaveAs($csvFile,6);import-csv $csvFile works pretty well too